# How to fix the centered div and footer overlap?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a main container that I centered vertically and horizontally and a footer that I want to stick to the bottom of the page:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div id="home-container">content goes here</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
body {
  min-height:350px;
}
#home-container {
    width: 730px;
  height:310px;
  position:absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%; 
  margin:-155px 0 0 -365px;
}
#footer {
  width:500px;
  border:1px solid red;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  bottom:0;
  margin-left:-250px;
}
```

The problem is that when I resize the browser's window height, home-container and footer overlap each other. Any ideas?

Comment: i'd go with not centering `#home-container` with `position: absolute;` and using http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: another thing to try is having a div in the content that is the same height as the footer, to push it down.

Comment: or another - responsive - solution would be to check on load and on resize whether client height is bigger than `home-container`'s and `footer`'s heights added together and changing their css accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
body {
      min-height:350px;
      text-align:center;
}
#home-container {
      text-align: left;
      width: 730px;
      height:310px;
     display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px
}
#footer {
     display:inline-block;
    width:500px;
      text-align: left;
      border:1px solid red;
      bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of what @schmidt382 said:

Add this to your CSS:

```
body {
min-width:640px;
}
```

By setting a minimum width, the `body` of the page will only shrink to that size and no smaller.  Just set that to whatever size you need to keep the divs from moving around awkwardly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#home-container {
top: 50%
margin-top: -310px;
width: 730px;
height:310px;
position:absolute; 
left:0;
right:0;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
#footer {
width:500px;
border:1px solid red;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```